# How to say "The path he is going along"

Tags: verb, participle

Is it

> Der Weg, er ist gehend entlang?

or

> Der Weg, er ist entlang gehend?

I want to use the present participle.

Comment: You **can't** use the present participle the same way you can in English because there is no continouus form in German. Also, in sentences like these the relative pronoun is mandatory.

Comment: What does your textbook say?

Comment: @Robert Afaik textbooks aren't very strong in translating sentences. To me, both looks correct, both not being a native speaker, I am very bad in "how does it sound" questions.

Comment: @peterh I am not saying that textbooks will have that particular sentence, but they will have general rules on constructing sentences and on when / how the participle is used.

Comment: Wrong close reason, people... reopened and please have a look a this: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/community-moderation-robo-reviews-dont-help-anybody

Comment: Are you speaking of a concrete physical path, or a metaphorical path? The proper wording of the German sentence can vary considerably depending on context. Please add context to your sentence!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann It was a metaphore, written by a Korean woman, I thought it is grammatically weird in some part. It goes like this : " Ich denke immer an den Weg. Der gegangene Weg, jetztige Weg
und weiter gehende Weg...ich denke daran. "  Is `weiter gehende Weg` correct? (I guess she meant `the way(path) to be taken further ahead`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Der Weg, den er entlanggeht."

I don't think you can use the present participle here, only when you have some simultaneous action: "Den Weg entlanggehend redete er über das Wetter."

Comment: *Entlang gehend* or *entlanggehend*?

Comment: You're right it's *entlanggehend* - thought it was split according to NDR. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I only know this as

> Der Weg, den er beschreitet.

FWIW, *is going* is a typical English form. In German, that form (using the present participle) is not used. They simply use the present tense of *to go*.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be also simply

> Der Weg, den er geht

Appropriate wording depends on where you want to use that sentence. You did not give any context, so there are many possible ways to express this; options would be restricted if we knew the context.